# Anaconda Python3.5 on Win10 after update: cannot load any dll

Tags: python, dll, anaconda, python-import, jupyter-notebook

As I updated Windows10 Anaconda Python is not finding any longer all the dll's...

```
import numpy as np

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41461b2e8b6b> in <module>()
      1 #from __future__ import division # uncomment this if using Python 2.7
----> 2 import numpy as np
      3 from scipy import signal
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

C:\Users\Ruggero\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, \
     13                 obj2sctype, zeros

C:\Users\Ruggero\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     12         os.environ[envkey] = '1'
     13         env_added.append(envkey)
---> 14 from . import multiarray
     15 for envkey in env_added:
     16     del os.environ[envkey]

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

this happens for all the dll's such as scipy,matplotlib etc.

Comment: Probably an issue with MSVC runtime. Presumably you've tried reinstallation?

Comment: yes I did it. still doesn't work...

Comment: What did you reinstall

Comment: anaconda python

Comment: And the packages?

Comment: they should all be included in anaconda

Comment: OK, gotcha. Have you searched Anaconda forum. Smells like a pure Anaconda issue.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? I have the same issue on Windows 10. I have tried removal and reisnstall without success. Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     12         os.environ[envkey] = '1'
     13         env_added.append(envkey)
---> 14 from . import multiarray
     15 for envkey in env_added:
     16     del os.environ[envkey]